# How to call time from time.h with Cython?

Tags: python, time, cython

I am trying to load time.h directly with Cython instead of Python's `import time` but it doesn't work.

All I get is an error

```
Call with wrong number of arguments (expected 1, got 0)
```

with the following code

```
cdef extern from "time.h" nogil:
    ctypedef int time_t
    time_t time(time_t*)

def test():
    cdef int ts
    ts = time()


    return ts
```

and

```
Cannot assign type 'long' to 'time_t *'
```

with the following code

```
cdef extern from "time.h" nogil:
    ctypedef int time_t
    time_t time(time_t*)

def test():
    cdef int ts
    ts = time(1)


    return ts
```

with math log I can simply do

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double log10(double x)
```

How comes it is not possible with **time**?

Comment: The parameter to `time` is the **address** (i.e.: "pointer") of a `time_t` value to fill _or NULL_.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux thanx for your response. I opted to use *NULL* as the parameter and it works. Can it be considered safe right?

Comment: I posted my reply as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter to `time` is the **address** (i.e.: "pointer") of a `time_t` value to fill *or NULL*.

To quote `man 2 time`:

> **`time_t time(time_t *t);`**
>
> [...]
>
> If t is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed to by t.

It is an oddity of some standard functions to both return a value and (possibly) store the same value in a provided address. It is perfectly safe to pass `0` as parameter as in most architecture *NULL* is equivalent to `((void*)0)`. In that case, `time` will only return the result, and will not attempt to store it in the provided address.

Comment: From what I understand *NULL* should almost always be used unless you're storing the result. In my case I don't need to store it so it's fine. Nice explanation by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

Pass in NULL to time. Also you can use the builtin libc.time:

```
from libc.time cimport time,time_t

cdef time_t t = time(NULL)
print t
```

which gives

```
1471622065
```

Comment: is this in seconds or nanoseconds ? Where is the documentation of cimport time ?

Comment: @Sylvain this uses `time` from `libc`. You can find docs by googling libc time. You should end up at the [libc docs here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getting-the-Time.html).

The `time_t` type is defined in [libc docs here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Types.html).

You can also see how the libc time library is wrapped by Cython in the Cython source code [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/cpython/time.pxd).