# How to measure time up to millisecond in Cython?

Tags: python, c, time, cython

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533293/how-to-call-time-from-time-h-with-cython-i-cant-get-it-to-work), but I would like to get better timing precision than a second: is this possible with some function of libc?

This is to use inside `with nogil`, so of course no Python is allowed...

Comment: In which part of your cython? `.pyx` or `.c[pp]`? For c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833094/get-a-timestamp-in-c-in-microseconds. There are many ways to do it in c++. Then maybe you can make a wrapper in .pyx.

Comment: @XinHuang in .pyx, I don't even have a .c (except for the one generated by cython)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use POSIX [clock_gettime()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime):

```
from posix.time cimport clock_gettime, timespec, CLOCK_REALTIME

cdef timespec ts
cdef double current
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts)
current = ts.tv_sec + (ts.tv_nsec / 1000000000.)
```

This snippet store in `current` the number of seconds since epoch with up to a nanosecond precision (depending on your system).

You can also use [gettimeofday()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday), but it is now deprecated:

> POSIX.1-2008 marks gettimeofday() as obsolete, recommending the use of clock_gettime(2) instead.

Answer (score -5):

Why dont you use datetime? For instance datetime.datetime.now() will give you current time value including milliseconds.

Comment: This is Python, I'm looking for something in C (in a with nogil section...)